# Check for an empty string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have a little question. Seems easy but I don't get it working.
All I want is check if a string is empty or not. Here's what I have so far:

```
if(mystring.text != @""){
    myPath = [myPath stringByAppendingString:mystring.text];
}
```

Comment: In Objective-C, when comparing strings, always remember to use `isEqualToString:`. Comparing it like this will not work.

Comment: Check this : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/better-way-to-check-empty-string.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compare an `NSString` to another one, you would use `isEqualToString`. You're checking for inequality, so it would be:

```
NSString *text = ...;

if (![text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    ...
}
```

But really, since you're just checking if the string is empty, you'll want something like

```
NSString *text = ...;

if ([text length] != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Note that if `text` is `nil`, the code in the `if`-statement will not execute. This is because `[nil length]` will return `0`. For more information about that, see ["Sending Messages to nil"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7) in Apple's documentation.

---

I suspect `mystring.text` is an `NSString` in your case, so it would be

```
if ([mystring.text length] != 0) {
    myPath = [myPath stringByAppendingString:mystring.text];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like it should :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can try below few lines of code:

```
NSString *trimedString = [someString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


if(trimedstr != [NSNull null]&& ![trimedstr isEqualToString:@""])
{
    if([trimedstr length]>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", trimedstr);
    }
    else
     NSLog(@"%@",@"this is empty string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like:

```
if(someString && [someString lenght])
    // string is not empty
```

Comment: The first check is unnecessary; if `someString` is `nil`, `[someString length]` will return a false-y value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I usually check if the length is > 0 for a positive test case, which also handles if nil.

something like: `if ([someString length] > 0) { // do something with someString }`